# Post Apocalyptic YA series 4 tribes around a city

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, post-apocalyptic

A series of popular YA novels form the late 90's, about a kid coming of age in a post apocalyptic tribe, one of four tribes, each one a different compass point, set around a central city.

The occupants of the central city have it all, all the shiny tech & unlike the post apocalyptic humans living in the 4 surrounding tribes, they are tall and fair.

Our protagonist is some kind of genetic anomaly though; he's tall and fair, just like the people of the city. When he's old enough he travels into the city, as the only time the outsiders are allowed inside the city is as cleaners, removing trash.

Comment: Lol. Basically the plot of Gattaca

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)